# using gdb to check sprintf() function step by step

Tags: c, printf, overlap

I have a program in C as followings:

```
char str[50] = {0};
int a = 15;
sprintf(str, "%d", a);
printf("%s\n", str);
```

It can get the correct result -- 15. But if I use gdb to check the sprintf() function step by step, "sprintf.c: No such file or directory." is shown and then it is killed. Why that happens? Actually, I used the sprintf() function in another project and now it occurs overlap. I doubt if there any dangers to use the sprintf() function? How can I avoid it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sprintf` (but beware, it is unsafe so obsolete, and you *should* use [snprintf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/snprintf.html), e.g. `snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "%d", a);` in your case).

It is just that, because your libc was not compiled with debug information, you cannot *step inside* the execution of `sprintf` (except by stepping on individual *machine* instructions).

The danger of `sprintf` is well known, it can make a [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). This is why you should not use it and use `snprintf` instead (or, if your platform has it and you want a dynamically allocated string, [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) which is available on most Linux systems).

BTW the Linux man page [sprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sprintf.3.html) explicitly says:

> ```
>    Because sprintf() and vsprintf() assume an arbitrarily long string,
>    callers must be careful not to overflow the actual space; this is
>    often impossible to assure.  Note that the length of the strings
>    produced is locale-dependent and difficult to predict.  Use
>    snprintf() and vsnprintf() instead (or asprintf(3) and vasprintf(3)).
> ```

It is sometimes quite useful to take into account the result of `snprintf` (which is the number of bytes actually needed for the computed string, which could be larger than the given size limit enforced on the result).